# What are some preventives or palliatives for vocal cord strain (from "overuse")?

Tags: recovery, endurance, breathing

I am going to be delivering a lecture 75-80 minutes in length. In practicing it lately, I find that my throat/vocal cords are a little fatigued afterwards and sometimes during the rehearsal. I'm not used to talking that much or for that long.

Is there something I can do either to help prevent this strain (exercises? drink orange juice? beer?) or to help soothe my pipes afterwards, to be ready for the next vocal marathon?

I may eventually do a couple of these performances per week, and I find that my voice sounds better when it's rested and "strong." It starts sounding "overworked" and croaky otherwise.

I thought of asking this on the "health" site, but figure that is more about illnesses and ailments, whereas this question is more about fitness, perhaps.